# Best way to run Windows GUI application with privilege from daemon

Tags: windows, service

I'm developing a Windows application that must execute other GUI programs with privileges (executed as administrator).

### Scope

- My application is a "daemon", a long-running process that it will be launched with no user action;
- My application must be executed as administrator (privileges elevation);
- Processes executed by my application must be executed as administrator and must display on the screen.

### Approach

Firstly, I developed my application as Windows service. I thought that it was the best way to run programs with privileges but services can't run programs that use the GUI session.

This restriction has been introduced by Microsoft with Windows Vista. An article from Microsoft - [Impact of Session 0 Isolation on Services and Drivers in Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/design/dn653293(v=vs.85)) - explains these changes. I tried to change the user who runs my service but this isolation appears to apply for all services.

### Purpose

So my question is "**What's the best way to run a program that it will launch another program with elevation of privileges (executed as administrator) with no action from user ?**"

Currently, the only once idea to solve my problem is to register my application into **Task Scheduler** but I think that it probably exists a best way.

Comment: What *problem* are you trying to solve? This question is asking about your proposed solution. This is known as the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: I'm searching for recommendations and best practices about "How to run GUI app from daemon". (Explanations are only to describe my research)

Comment: "*Daemon"* doesn't mean anything. Again, what **problem** are you trying to solve?

Comment: What's the best way to start a background program with privilege whose purpose is to start an application which displays something at screen?

Comment: **Use case:** when I start my program in background (same way systemd would do), the other programs it'll launch won't be rendered into user session.

Comment: **Example:**
**Step 1**. my program (A) is running as Windows service (with privilege);
**Step 2**. (A) execute GUI application (B) ;
**Step 3**. (B) is running but no window is displayed.

Comment: Don't keep repeating the question. I wouldn't have commented, if the question were clear. I have no idea what *"background program"* or *"with privilege"* mean to you.

Comment: I mean by "background program", a program that is running at the start of user session without requiring user intervention. And I mean by "program with privilege", a program which has been executed as administrator.

Comment: There's an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62930631/edit) link underneath your question, so that you can include that information. This helps others to understand, that your notion of *"background program"* doesn't mean, say, a system service that starts without a user having logged into the system. Though *"executed as administrator"* is still very fuzzy. What **privileges** does your (GUI) application actually need? *"Being administrator"* is not a privilege in itself, and different systems can be configured to grant different privileges to administrators.

Comment: I hope to have complete and present again my question with all missing details. Your feedbacks are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Services have not been designed to interact in current session (user session). Services are running into Session 0 since the deployment of Windows Vista.

Explanations about this changes can be found in "[Impact of Session 0 Isolation on Services and Drivers in Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/design/dn653293(v=vs.85))".

I have found another Microsoft post "[Launching an interactive process from Windows Service in Windows Vista and later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/winsdk/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later)" but we can read at the beginning:

> The first thing you should do about it is that, don't do it. There are many limitations, bad implications and restrictions involved into it.

Windows Services are definitely a wrong solution for this use case. The unique solution that I can found is the **Task Scheduler**.